# How do you use the G2A4 in Titanfall?

Tags: titanfall

There is a rifle in Titanfall called the G2A4.

- It does fairly poor damage (3 body hits, or 4 suppressed).
- It has poor accuracy (forget about long range).
- It has a poor rate of fire (no semi or full auto, fires as fast as trigger pulls with an attachment that further reduces accuracy).
- It has a small magazine and an average reload time.

Close up a shotgun, LMG or SMG will own you every time. Mid range an LMG, carbine, hemlock or even smart pistol will. Long range both snipers will outclass you completely, and again the carbine or hemlock are still better.

There is a challenge where you have to get a large number of kills with this gun, but it feels almost completely worthless - in my hands this gun is worse than any of the side-arm pistols.

Given how well balanced the rest of the guns are this seems unlikely. What am I doing wrong with this gun? How should I use it?

Please include *how* you use this gun successfully.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The G2A4 is designed to be a purely mid range marksman rifle. As you are aware, since it is single shot, it really struggles in short range engagements. It shoots slightly faster than the longbow so it can win out ranged firefights with it, but it still can't compete with the longbow at longer ranges.

I will agree with you that the G2A4 seems a bit... underpowered compared to other weapons, but thats only because it doesn't suit me. I have seen the gun destroy if it's in the right hands.

I don't know why you think it has low accuracy. It's defining feature is how pinpoint accurate it is. Where ever you are aiming, it ***will*** hit that point.

Maps with a lot of enclosed space and Close combat, this gun **will** be mostly unusable. Some maps Angel City, Fracture, and Colony have a lot of nice open spaces that really let the gun shine.

How to use it effectively is simple aim at them and shoot... how well you can aim determines how effective the gun will be. (tip: headshots are worth it)

The designed range classification/"superiority" goes a little like this (from shortest to farthest):

Shotgun->R97->Smart Pistol->CAR->Rc101->Spitfire->Hemlok->G2A4->Longbow->Kraber

Comment: It looks like the game designers have found it to be too weak too: http://www.titanfall.com/game-update-four

Comment: Just saw that patch notes yesterday. Not sure how much it affects my answer, but we'll see.

Comment: I think I felt it had low accuracy in part because of the recoil, but also due to how the damage falls off at range, which I hadn't realised - I'm glad they're fixing that.